# React : Cannot use multiple MaterialUI component in JavaScript page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, material-ui, frontend

I use multiple [MaterialUI Card](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-card/) as shown on the following demo, but even I use `key` value and mapped components have different key values, when I expand the card or select a value on the Select list, all of the cards are expanded or the select values are changed to the same value.

I m anew in React and have never used MUI before, but the problem is probably an id problem. So, should I pass the key values to the related onChange methods so that only the related card is expanded and only related select value is changed? How?

[DEMO](https://codesandbox.io/s/xenodochial-shockley-73l4gz?file=/demo.js)

Comment: Does anybody else have never used Material UI components?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are sharing one boolean between all three cards. You can use ids or names to expand the card you want:

```js
const handleExpandClick = (panel, isExpanded) => () => {
  // if panel is already expanded close it, if not expand it.
  setExpanded(isExpanded ? false : panel);
};

<ExpandMore
  expand={expanded === recipe.name}
  onClick={handleExpandClick(recipe.name, expanded === recipe.name)}
  aria-expanded={expanded === recipe.name}
  aria-label="show more"
>
```

And your `collapse` component:

```js
<Collapse
  in={expanded === recipe.name}
  timeout="auto"
  unmountOnExit
>
```

In order to DRY, you can define a variable at the beginning of the map:

```js
const isExpanded = expanded === recipe.name
```

[image: Edit nice-dew-s6i7my]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. It is not working, but I think I made a mistake. Could you pls check these points >>>

Comment: **1.** Is this lien correct? `const handleExpandClick = (panel, isExpanded) => () => {` ? I am not sure if `() =>` part is redundant or not?

Comment: **2.** How should I define `const isExpanded = expanded === recipe.name
`? I tried using `useState(false)`, but not worked. Can you also add it by updating other fields if necessary?

Comment: By the way, I think there is a problem with the `handleExpandClick` method. What about keeping id value of the currently expanded recipe?

Comment: @william I added a minimal sandbox example.

Comment: Do you have an idea for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75241307/custom-alert-component-cannot-be-displayed-after-first-initialiation ?